# using sql union on same table in cakephp find query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

let's say I have a query like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id < 5 order by id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id > 5  LIMIT 1)
```

How can I translate the above query into a [CakePHP find('all')](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#find-all) query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Using Model::find('neighbors')

Rewriting this to a find('all') will be problematic, however `find('neighbors')` may fit your requirements;

See the documentation [`find('neighbors')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-neighbors)

This should give you the data you need, but you will probably have to adopt your code a bit to have it working correctly with the different 'layout' of the returned array;

```
 $data = $this->User->find('neighbors', array('field' => 'id', 'value' => 5));
```

**update**

Just saw you're on CakePHP 1.3, the link posted above points to the 2.x part of the documentation. Although similar, this is the documentation for CakePHP 1.3:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#find-neighbors

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird I don't think the generated query performs a `union`, but it *does* return the record "before" and "after" the requested record, which is the result the OP was looking for.