# MySQL little complex query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, sorting

I am working on an mysql query where in I need the previous and next id from the results set. I was able to get it without search query. But when doing search obviously the ids wont help... It would be other fields based on the params.

So, I am running two different queries, one for the current userid i.e. 123.. and another for previous userid and next userid.

The query is like this.... 
`select fields from users where (( 
        id = IFNULL((select min(id) from users where id > 123),0) 
        or  id = IFNULL((select max(id) from users where id < 123),0)
      ) AND (username like "%john%"))`

With the above I am getting the users prev and next ids... but when I have a search going on example 'john', I am not able to get the next id and previous id from the search results? Also I have alphabetic sorting A-Z and Z-A. So i will have to sort by name as Order by name Asc, desc.

Is storing search results ids in sessions is a good idea including pagination ids?

What are the options to achieve this? please share your thoughts?

Comment: Seems similar to this question; check my answer on that one as it may be helpful; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140208/using-sql-union-on-same-table-in-cakephp-find-query/16158060#16158060

Answer (score 0):

For getting the next/prev of other fields that you're sorting on, you'd need two separate queries done in a union.

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
WHERE whatever=whatever
ORDER BY sortfield DESC limit 1,1

UNION ALL

SELECT ..
FROM users
WHERE whatever=whatever
ORDER BY sortfield ASC LIMIT 1,1
```

The first query gets the "previous" record, previous being defined by whatever you're actually sorting on. The other query reverses the sense, so that you get the "next" record using the same order by, with the order reversed (DESC -> ASC).

You could use a LIMIT 0,1 on one of those queries, which'd allow the actual "current" record to be included in the result set as well. But don't do it on both, or the union will cause a duplicate "current".